# Max One Hour records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to display latest max one hour records in MySQL my table having following column id,value1,value2,date,date_time the records is

```
id    value1  value2  date          date_time
21      12      10    2015-01-21    2015-01-21 01:23:43
21      7        4    2015-01-21    2015-01-21 01:29:32
21      5        3    2015-01-21    2015-01-21 13:25:54
21      8       13    2015-01-21    2015-01-21 13:45:21
21      8       78    2015-01-21    2015-01-21 02:23:25
21      3        7    2015-01-21    2015-01-21 02:43:25
```

From above records i want to display records 3-4 that is having maximum hour(13) records please give me your guidance to display the max one hour records

Comment: Unless there's a situation in which `date` and DATE(`date_time`) differ, there can be no merit in storing `date`!!

Comment: date column is for another use thats why date column required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So 
`select * from your_table where hour(date_time) in (select hour(max(date_time)) from your_table)`

Comment: what error? Did you replace your_table for the name of you table?

Comment: It was missing a '(' . I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

select * from your_table where convert(date_time, datetime) between current_timestamp - interval 1 hour and current_timestamp

Comment: No Sandro Eric i am not expecting last one hour record from current time i want to display last maximum one hour record from the table

Comment: So select * from your_table where hour(date_time) in (select hour(max(date_time) from your_table)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select * from 
( select * from table order by date_time desc ) as q0
where timediff( now(), date_time ) < "00:01:00 000000";
```

Comment: It's just p-code - you'll need to put in the correct table name, columns,etc

Comment: I am giving correct table name and field it is giving error in near time_diff

Comment: updated - correct function is *timediff* not *time_diff*

Comment: Did you update the data so it's in the correct range for a test?

Comment: No in my situation the data was not updated every hour